# Kubuntu audio duplex input problem

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, skype, microphone

Kubuntu 14.04
Kernel 3.1.3.0-32-generic

Hello, My problem here is my sound input suddenly stopped working properly. One day I decided to use my laptop when I found out that my applications audio was using my input as well as my output, and my microphone was not being registered. For example: If I go into a skype call, and play music in the background, skype can hear my music but not my voice. I already tried using pavucontrol and alsamixer to no avail. Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch alsamixer in a terminal, press F6 to select your main sound card (not HDMI), F5 to display all controls , then use arrow keys to move thru , spacebar or "m" to change state :

- Check  "loopback" switch is off
- Change "mic" level
- Check  main "capture" switch is in "capture " state (not off)  and increase its level. (sometimes , there is an additional  "mic  "  capture switch  : must be in "capture " state)

Some of these settings can also be done with Pavucontrol  but not all:
In pavucontrol "input device " tab, select correct sound card (not hdmi) and  input (mic)

Comment: In alsamixer I don't see any "loopback" switch, and capture was already up. And in the input devices tab, The only thing is "Bult in audio analog Stereo" and the ports are either "Internal microphone" or "Headphones(unplugged)"

Comment: try to run Alsainfo: Copy this command in a terminal and post the url which will store the result : `wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh`

Comment: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=aee016e9a05cfc4e8426d565301e8555feec15a7 Sorry for the wait.

Comment: looks ok, can you try to test recording with Audacity: can you record your mic ?

Comment: Audacity seems to record fine. I guess it's just skype? Also this message was spammed in the terminal when I launched audacity: "ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave" Not sure if it helps but oh well.

Comment: message is normal . do you see skype in the pavucontrol  recording tab ?

Comment: Ah yes, I checked recording and changed the input from "Monitor of Built-In analog stereo" To "Built-in analog stereo, and it worked great. Thanks much for your time!